# terms query not working in Elastic search with value having space in it

Tags: elasticsearch

We need to get the data based on multiple values.
So I am trying to use terms query in elastic search for modelNumber field.
But it is not working as expected.can anyone let me know what is wrong with the query.

```
POST index_name/_Search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "modelNumber": [
              "test 1234rthg-1234-1234512-2345",
              "testMode11l-123-rtyu-xyz11"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "userId": [
              "123",
              "VALUE2"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the mapping of the field `modelNumber`?

Answer (score 0):

> [Terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) returns documents that contain one or more exact terms in
> a provided field.

If you have not explicitly defined any index mapping, then you need to add .keyword to the modelNumber field. This uses the keyword analyzer instead of the standard analyzer (notice the ".keyword" after modelNumber field).

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "modelNumber.keyword": [                   // note this
              "test 1234rthg-1234-1234512-2345",
              "testMode11l-123-rtyu-xyz11"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "userId": [
              "123",
              "VALUE2"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

OR you need to modify the mapping of `modelNUmber` field as -

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "modelNumber": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```